# Create an outgoing webhook in Teams for an incoming phone call

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, webhooks, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

I want to be notified when I receive an incoming **phone** call using Microsoft Teams Phone.  For this, I thought of creating a Microsoft Teams Outgoing Webhook.
Goal: Call an HTTP -endpoint with some information about the call so another (windows) application can react to that information.

I have:

- Microsoft Teams Phone enabled
- A fixed number associated with my Azure AD user

However, it seems its only possible to create a webhook on a Team itself, not on my user.  Does that mean I need to create a new Team that includes all users making use of this functionality? (eg. all users having a Microsoft Teams Phone license).  This "Phone" -functionality is not specific to a team, but to a user, so I'm unsure how to proceed)

Looking at my Teams account, I couldn't find any option for connectivity there.  So that's no option either..

I'm not sure this is possible using the Microsoft Graph API.  I couldn't really find a meaningful answer.  Information on this is sparse, mostly targeted at chat/meetings (where the *team* makes more sense), and/or out-of-date given changes on the Communication part of the API.

**UPDATE 2023-03-29**:
I found LyncWizard's TeamWizard application that seems to do mostly of what I'm interested in.  However, I still would prefer to do this ourselves using .NET Core stack / Graph API.  Since this app does handle those incoming calls, this should be possible.
Link: http://www.lyncwizard.com/products.html#TeamsWizard_Hotkey

**UPDATE 2023-06-19**:
Azure Communication Services seems promising and to link existing phonenumbers/infrastructure, it seems we could use: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/concepts/telephony/direct-routing-provisioning.

But, if I'm not mistaken, it would mean all communication only goes through the ACS from that point on.  So how would that map to my use-case: A call comes in to my dedicated Teams number.

- The call goes through ACS where my application (desktop client) listens to CallIncoming and CallEnded events.
- Teams-client notifies me of an incoming call. Important: it's not the desktop app that handles the call itself, that should always be the Teams client.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Currently it's not feasible using graph API.

Comment: @Boezie have you been able to develop an application similar to LyncWizard?

Comment: @cashmere: I managed to get it working as described here:
https://blog.cloudcyclist.net/handling-an-incoming-ms-teams-call-within-your-application

Answer (score 0):

Currently it's not feasible using graph API.

Comment: But, if not Graph API, then what options do I have to implement this?  Does that mean, using Teams Phone, I can only call and receive from within Teams?  Is there no supported way for my external application to receive those events?

Comment: We are checking this with engineering team. We will let you know once we get any updates from them.

Comment: Could you please refer below document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/concepts/teams-endpoint

Comment: Thanks a lot already, I do think we're getting a bit closer.
I've updated my original answer with some additional info and questions.